# Not Returning Updates to YAML file and Returning TypeError on String Update

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pyyaml

I have code which is supposed to grab a YAML file and read it in, (does successfully), but is also supposed to be able to update the YAML return one of three options:

- Successful update message with all changes to file.
- Unsuccessful update message with possible places where the file did not update correctly.
- Let user know he/she did not pass any changes to be made to the file (redundant entries in the YAML file).

The second and third options works well, but the first is returning `TypeError: string indices must be integers` or `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` whenever I update any values outside of the nested dictionaries in my dictionary d.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
class YAML_Config:
    '''
    Class used to interact with .YAML filetypes. Allows the creation of objects \
    that can be manipulated and save certain YAML files and configuration settings.
    '''

    def __init__(self, filename):
        '''
        Initial defintion. Defines the location for saving a new .YAML file or for loading \
        a previous one. The dictionary corresponding to the .YAML file is saved to self.dict. \
        If this is a new .YAML file, an empty dictionary is created.

        Input Arguments:
            -filename: (string) The name of the file where the current .YAML file is \
            located or the new .YAML will be saved.
        '''
        #Get the filename and save it to the class as a property.
        self.file = filename

        #Check if the file exists...
        if os.path.isfile(self.file):

            #Prepare to open the file with reading capabilities
            with open(self.file,'r') as infile:

                #Get a dictionary with all of the YAML informatin.
                yaml_dict = yaml.load(infile)

        #If the file does not exist...
        else:

            #Create an empty dictionary to save all YAML data.
            yaml_dict = {}

            #Create an empty .yaml file with the dictionary.
            with open(self.file, 'w') as infile:

                #Save updated dictionary to YAML file.
                yaml.dump(yaml_dict, infile, default_flow_style=False)

            print('YAML configuration file not found. New, empty dictionary, and .yaml file created.')

        self.dict=yaml_dict




    def update_value(self, kwargs):
        '''
        Used to update YAML files, and checks that the files were updated properly.
        '''
        #If these are not keyword arguments, then throw an error.
        assert kwargs, 'Input Error'

        #Get the YAML dictionary before it is updated.
        yaml_dict = self.dict


        #Make a copy of the dictionary to compare against later.
        yaml_dict_original = copy.deepcopy(self.dict)

        #Check if the dictionary is nonetype. This happens if the file is new as the file is empty.
        if yaml_dict_original is None:

            #Redefine orginal dictionary as an empty dictionary.
            yaml_dict_original={}

            #The new dictionary will simply be what is passed to the function.
            yaml_dict=kwargs

        else:

            #Update the original dictionary and update it with the arguments passed.
            #This also updates self.dict as yaml_dict is simply a reference to
            #that dictionary, not a copy of it.
            yaml_dict.update(kwargs)


        #Check if changes were made
        if (yaml_dict==yaml_dict_original) is False:

            #Open the YAML file to write to it.
            with open(self.file, 'w') as outfile:

                #Save updated dictionary to YAML file.
                yaml.dump(self.dict, outfile, default_flow_style=False)


    #Check that the file actually updated properly:

            #Double-check the file that it actually updated.
            with open(self.file, 'r') as infile:

                lastupdate = yaml.load(infile)

            #Get any nonmatching values between what should be in the YAML file and what actually is.
            errors = { k : yaml_dict[k] for k in set(yaml_dict) - set(lastupdate) }

            #Find out what changed in the YAML file.
            edits = { k : yaml_dict_original[k] for k in set(yaml_dict_original) - set(lastupdate) }

            #Check if errors is not empty. Evaluating dictionaries as boolean either returns True (not empty)
            #or False (empty).
            if bool(errors) is True:

                #First line of return print statement.
                print('The following entries did not update successfully:')

                #Loop through keys in errors
                for n in errors:

                    #Print the current key
                    print (n)

                    #Loop through entries of current key
                    for m in errors[n]:

                        #Print current entry of current key
                        print (m,':',errors[n][m])

            #Saved properly, check for edits and display to user.
            else:

                #Find where any edits were made.
                edits = {k: yaml_dict_original[k] for k in yaml_dict_original if k in lastupdate and yaml_dict_original[k] != lastupdate[k]}

                #Show user what edits were successfuly made.
                print('%s was successfully updated with the following changes:' %  os.path.basename(self.file))

                #Loop through keys in edits
                for n in edits:

                    #Print the current key
                    print (n)

                    #Loop through entries of current key
                    for m in edits[n]:

                        #Print current entry of current key
                        print (m,':',edits[n][m])

        #If no changes were made...        
        else:

            #Show user what edits were successfuly made.
            print('No changes to %s were passed. File not updated.' %  

    os.path.basename(self.file))



test=YAML_Config(r'...Path\Python Work\yaml_test.yaml')

d = {'A': 7, 'B':{'C':'D', 'D':False, 'E':'Julio'},\
     'The Real C': {'J?':'Yes, this is J.', 'K' : 241},'Q' : 'PQ'}

test.update_value(d)
```

First Error Section:

```
b = {'A': '', 'B':{'C':'D', 'D':False, 'E':'Julio'},\
         'The Real C': {'J?':'Yes, this is J.', 'K' : 241},'Q' : 'PQ'}

#TypeError: string indices must be integers.
test.update_value(b)
```

Second Error Section:

```
f = {'A': 7, 'B':{'C':'D', 'D':False, 'E':'Julio'},\
         'The Real C': {'J?':'Yes, this is J.', 'K' : 241},'Q' : 2}

#TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
test.update_value(f)
```

The YAML file updates every time I run this code. So the actual updating is working, but I'm not really sure why I can't find the indices of the dictionary updates. I'm a little rusty on my Python, and new to YAML, so I may be missing something obvious here.

I'm using Python 3.6.5.

Comment: The extra newlines force reader to do more scrolling than is necessary, and other non-[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) formatting also don't make your code more readable.  I guess you don't care about comments in your input file, nor YAML 1.2 conformance if you are using PyYAML, or do you?

Comment: Please note that because PyYAML 4.1 was retracted from PyPI, it is once more dangerous (and unnecessary) to use `yaml.load()` you should make a habit of always explicitly using `yaml.safe_load()` when using PyYAML.

Comment: Can you please update the program, so that it throws the error that you get.

Comment: Hey Anthon, thanks for some of the PEP8 formatting. I had not cared too much about `yaml.load()` vs `yaml.safe_load()` as all .yaml files I will be using are created by this program. From what I understand of the difference between the two, it is a difference of being able to execute code embedded in the yaml files, which I would never expect to happen as no other user will be interacting with these files.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean about comments in the input file, but I'm using PyYAML 3.12. If you mean in-line comments in the .YAML files, you would be correct. I don't really care for them as the files should already be self-explanatory with what the keynames will be for the real files I will be making.
I updated my code and it returned the same errors when performing the same operations: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` and `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: I am using 3.6.2 . I only added `import sys, os, yaml, copy` to the above and it runs without problem. Once more: **Can you please update the program in your question so that when you copy and paste it, and then run it, without further interaction, it produces the error that you get?**

Comment: As I originally stated in the bullet points, the errors only occur after updating the YAML files, not when they are originally created. I have added two sections of code which can be copy+pasted after the original code to produce the corresponding errors in the comment above the line where it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code goes wrong on this line:

```
                    # Loop through entries of current key
                    for m in edits[n]:
```

and at that point `edits` is a dict:  `{A: 7}` (as A is the key with a changed value). Your code seems only to anticipate a change in a complex value (like the one for `B`), because if you would have done:

```
b = {'A': 7, 'B':{'C':'D', 'D':True, 'E':'Julio'},\
        'The Real C': {'J?':'Yes, this is J.', 'K' : 241},'Q' : 'PQ'}
```

you get:

```
test.yaml was successfully updated with the following changes:
B
C : D
D : False
E : Julio
```

So you should rethink your "reporting" and update it to something that can not only handle values that are `dict`s , but also `list`s and primitives (YAML scalars: string, int, boolean, etc.):

```
            # Show user what edits were successfuly made.
            print('{} was successfully updated with the following changes:'.format(os.path.basename(self.file)))
            # Loop through keys in edits
            for n in edits:
                # Loop through entries of current key
                if isinstance(edits[n], dict):
                    # Print the current key
                    print(n)
                    for m in edits[n]:
                        # Print current entry of current key
                        print(m, ':', edits[n][m])
                elif isinstance(edits[n], list):
                    # Print the current key followed by the elements
                    print(n)
                    for m in edits[n]:
                        # Print current entry of current key
                        print('- ', [m])
                else:  # scalar
                    print('{}: {}'.format(n, edits[n]))
```

and then your output will be:

```
test.yaml was successfully updated with the following changes:
A: 7
test.yaml was successfully updated with the following changes:
A: 
Q: PQ
```

(assuming you run the two extra updates after each other).